# Cannot build a basic project with curl on Mac (M2) for Raspberry Pi Pico

Tags: c, macos, cmake, apple-silicon

I am creating a basic c program for the raspberry pi pico w, I want it to basically log onto the internet and get the time, then using the time switch a relay either on or off.

I am using the curl library as that is what the internet suggests. My issue is I cannot even build the project. I get an the following error:

```
sys/socket.h: No such file or directory
  428 | #  include <sys/socket.h>
```

Please can you help me out with this?
here is a link if you could tell me what I am doing wrong that would be awesome: https://github.com/FlawlessCalamity/pico-realay-on-off/tree/main

Comment: Have you installed the necessary SDKs to do this cross compilation? [This](https://medium.com/@haraldfernengel/cross-compiling-c-c-from-macos-to-raspberry-pi-in-2-easy-steps-23f391a8c63) seems to be a good start otherwise.

Comment: Im just using the Pico not a full blown raspberry pi so I think this isn't 100% what I am looking for but I will give it a go, but yes I have installed the SDK and everything is working as it should on all basic projects

Comment: There may be some other version of that tutorial aimed at the Pico, but the point is that you need a toolchain/SDK for the target platform in order to do cross compilations (that is, compiling on one platform while targeting a different platform).

Comment: I think it's unlikely that libcurl has been ported to the Pico. I don't know if there are third party http libarries for the Pico, but you can certainly implement your own http client using lwip. There's one example [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-examples/blob/master/pico_w/wifi/tls_client/picow_tls_client.c), although that includes TLS support, so perhaps more complicated than you're looking for.

Comment: Are you aware that you can program the Pico extremely simply with Python?